# Call a child clases' __call method if it exists, and throw an exception if not

Tags: php, oop, magic-methods

[edit] updated the title to more accurately reflect the problem

The problem I am trying to solve is this: I need to know if a method was called via `parent::` and while I can use `debug_backtrace` it seems like there must be a better way to do this.

I've been looking into late static binding but perhaps I don't understand it well enough to fathom a solution.

The method in question is `__call` so I can't simply pass in an extra parameter as its an error to have more or less then exactly two.

The reason for trying to solve this problem is that the parent class has `__call` but the child may or may not have `_call`. If the child doesn't have it, and the parent doesn't dispatch the call, then I'd like to throw an exception or error. If the child does have the method then I'll return `false` (no we didn't handle this) and let the child `_call` method carry on.

So far my only working solution is to have the child call `parent::__call` wrapped in a try/catch block and have the parent throw an exception by default if it does not route the request.

ie.

```
class Parent {
  public function __call( $method, $params ) {
    if( preg_match( $this->valid, $method ) {
      $this->do_stuff();
      // if child has a call method, it would skip on true
      return true;
    }
    elseif( ** CHILD HAS CALL METHOD ** ) {
      // this would let the child's _call method kick in
      return false;
    }
    else {
      throw new MethodDoesNotExistException($method);
    }
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  public function __call( $method, $params ) {
    if( ! parent::__call( $method, $params ) ) {
      do_stuff_here();
    }
  }
}
```

While throwing an exception if the parent doesn't handle the method works, I'm just trying to see if there's a more elegant solution, as using exceptions for flow-controll doesn't seem quite right. But neither does using a stacktrace to figure out the caller, either.

Comment: What was it you did not understand when using late state binding?

Answer (score 4):

This should do in your parent class:

```
if (__CLASS__ != get_class($this))
```

Comment: This tells me the name of the child class and the name of the parent class, but doesn't actually let me determine if there is a child `_call` method

Comment: This will get you what you want, but I would suggest to OP that putting knowledge of your child classes into the parent class is a bad design approach.

Comment: @Will Well, it answers the question from the title. Your child class will always have a `__call` method, because it inherits it from the parent. You'd have to do a lot of introspection to figure out if your child class has a `__call` method of its own. This sounds like bad application structure though. The parent should not be aware of its children at all. The child overrides the parent where appropriate, nothing else.

Comment: @Will if the the call arrived from a class that is not itself, then it must have come from the child class (that is unless you have some other method in the child calling `parent::__call()` which would be an even crazier design approach).

Comment: @will you can do all of that from the child class without having to make the parent class aware of the existence of children.  Just do the try-catch with the call to parent class from child class as you suggested if you need to throw the exception in parent class.

Comment: I would add that I personally think it is better coding practice to `__call()` only for the purpose of throwing exceptions (i.e. an invalid method call on class), and specifically implement the methods that you want to use.  This makes it MUCH clearer what your intent is in the code, and makes it MUCH clearer how to go about overriding specific methods in child classes. If you are actually implementing extensive logic in your `__call()` method for a number of method calls and you make changes to that method, you risk breaking ALL method calls to the class, not just the one you changed.

Comment: @MikeBrant `__call` only affects undefined methods and in this case implements logic to be run before and after the method to be run, so I can add things like caching to a group of model methods by inheriting a class. In most cases, the inheriting class won't have its own call method but I wanted to make sure they *could*.

The other option of course would be to put method calls at the start and end of each method I want to so affect, This way I can inherit my class and name my methods `_cached_method` and call it as `$this->method`. Helps keep it DRY.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if this fits your needs and I also consider this kind of hacks to be really bad from the OO design point of view. However, it was a fun thing to code :)

```
<?php

class ParentClass 
  {
  public function __call( $method, $params ) 
  {
    if($method === 'one')
    {
      echo "Parent\n";
      return true;
    }
    elseif($this->shouldForwardToSubclass($method)) 
      {
        return false;
      }
    else 
    {
      throw new Exception("No method");
    }
  }

   protected function shouldForwardToSubclass($methodName)
   {
      $myClass = get_class($this);
      if (__CLASS__ != $myClass)
      {
        $classObject = new ReflectionClass($myClass);
        $methodObject = $classObject->getMethod('__call');
        $declaringClassName = $methodObject->getDeclaringClass()->getName();
        return $myClass == $declaringClassName;
      }
      else 
          {
            return false;
          }
}

}

class ChildClass1 extends ParentClass {
  public function __call( $method, $params ) {
    if( ! parent::__call( $method, $params ) ) 
    {
      echo "Child handle!\n";
    }
  }
}

class ChildClass2 extends ParentClass {
}
```

later doing:

```
$c = new ChildClass1();
$c->one();
$c->foo();

$c = new ChildClass2();
$c->foo();
```

would yield:

```
Parent
Child handle!
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'No method' in /home/andres/workspace/Playground/test.php:18
Stack trace:
#0 /home/andres/workspace/Playground/test.php(58): ParentClass->__call('foo', Array)
#1 /home/andres/workspace/Playground/test.php(58): ChildClass2->foo()
#2 {main}
```

HTH